# Attacking a "Mathematica can't solve" problem

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

*Mathematica* throws the following message when I try to solve the equation below

> "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve".

Setting $P_T = 0.5$, $\sigma=0.1$ and $S=1$ and plotting with $w$ from $0$ to $1$, however, provides clear indication the equation crosses through $0$.

**So, what are my options for advancing. At the very least, I would like numerical approximations**

[image]

```
Assuming[
 Subscript[P, T] >= 0 && Subscript[P, T] <= 1 && Subscript[w, 1] <= 1 && Subscript[w, 1] >= 0 && σ > 0,
 Solve[1/(6 σ^2 (-1 + Subscript[w, 1]) Subscript[w, 1])S ((Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]] - Log[Subscript[P, T] + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 Subscript[w, 1])]) Subscript[P,T] (Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]) - (6 σ^2 +Sqrt[3] σ (Log[-Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]] +Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]] - 2 Log[Subscript[P, T] + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 Subscript[w, 1])]) Subscript[P, T] + (-Log[-Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]] + Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Subscript[P, T]])\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(T\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[w, 1] + 6 σ^2 \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) == 0, Subscript[w,1]
  ]
]
```

Comment: See `NSolve` or `FindRoot`.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With[
 {Pt = 0.5, σ = 0.1 , S = 1},
 FindRoot[
  1/(6 σ^2 (-1 + w) w)
     S ((Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] - 
         Log[Pt + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt (Sqrt[3] σ + 
         Pt) - (6 σ^2 + 
         Sqrt[3] σ (Log[-Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] + 
            Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] - 
            2 Log[Pt + 
               Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt + (-Log[-Sqrt[
                 3] σ + Pt] + 
            Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt]) Pt^2) w + 6 σ^2 w^2) == 0
   , {w, 0.5}
  ]
 ]
(* {w -> 0.409537} *)
```

Comment: If given a range spec such as `0<=w<=10` then `NSolve` can find solutions although one is spurious. Giving exact values for the parameters fixes that issue though.

Answer (score 4):

Using exact numbers `Solve` will provide an exact solution expressed as a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object.

```
sol = With[{Pt = 1/2, σ = 1/10, S = 1}, 
    Solve[{1/(6 σ^2 (-1 + w) w) S ((Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] - 
             Log[Pt + Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt (Sqrt[3] σ + 
             Pt) - (6 σ^2 + 
             Sqrt[3] σ (Log[-Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] + 
                Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt] - 
                2 Log[Pt + 
                   Sqrt[3] σ (1 - 2 w)]) Pt + (-Log[-Sqrt[3] σ +
                    Pt] + Log[Sqrt[3] σ + Pt]) Pt^2) w + 
          6 σ^2 w^2) == 0, 0 <= w <= 1}, w]][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {w -> Root[{5 (5 + Sqrt[3]) Log[
        5 + Sqrt[3]] (-1 + #1) + (6 + 5 (-5 + Sqrt[3]) Log[5 - Sqrt[3]] - 
         6 #1) #1 + 
      5 Log[5 + Sqrt[3] - 2 Sqrt[3] #1] (5 + Sqrt[3] - 2 Sqrt[3] #1) &, 
    0.40953666596770227094}]} *)
```

The last argument to `Root` is the approximate numeric value

```
sol // N[#, 20] &

(* {w -> 0.40953666596770227094} *)
```

**EDIT:** Note that `Solve` does not use `Assumptions`

```
Options[Solve]

{Cubics -> True, GeneratedParameters -> C, InverseFunctions -> Automatic, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> 0, Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> True,
  VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> ∞}
```

Consequently, conditions from `Assuming` (e.g., `0 <= w <= 1`) are not used by `Solve` and must be entered as part of the "system `expr` of equations or inequalities".